# SQL SELECT GROUP BY a column and a time interval

Tags: mysql

I have a table in this way on MySql

```
POWERID | OBJECTID | REALPOWER | LASTUPDATE
```

`LASTUPDATE` is a `VARCHAR` field

The table gets on row for `OBJECTID` every 10 seconds with a `REALPOWER` value

I need to extract, for every `OBJECTID`, the average of `REALPOWER` for every 15 minutes, so, let's say for simplicity we have 1 hour history, i should finish with 4 rows for every `OBJECTID`.

I was trying with

```
select avg(REALPOWER), `OBJECTID`, max(LASTUPDATE) 
from POWER 
group by UNIX_TIMESTAMP('LASTUPDATE')/(15*60), 
         OBJECTID
```

but i get only 1 row for object...

Comment: `'LASTUPDATE'` is a string constant in your query

Comment: I vote to close these questions as a simple typographical error (remove the single quotes and the query should work).

Comment: sorry, thanks for pointing this out, i will close the question!